# Subgroups of $SL(n,F)$ which contain $B\cap SL(n,F)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, linear-groups

If $B$ is the usual Borel subgroup of $GL(n,F)$, then what are the subgroups of $SL(n,F)$ which contain $B\cap SL(n,F)$? I don't even know where to start! Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Are you really looking for all such subgroups, or just the closed ones (i.e. parabolic subgroups)?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear, I accidentally left out a word in the OP.

Comment: Yes, I actually inferred that word from the context. But without requiring the subgroups to be closed I don't think they have a nice description.

Comment: Is that so? That's a shame. For example, you probably already know that all subgroups of $GL(n,F)$ containing $B$ are the staircase groups. There isn't an analogous description for $SL(n,F)$?

Comment: Again, those are the closed subgroups containing $B$, not all the subgroups. And yes, for closed the precisely analogue carries over (as well as analogues for types other than $A$).